# Bootstrap Modal Pop Not Rendering in UC Browser in Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, uc-browser

I have a bootstrap modal popup its working all fine in all browser except UC Browser in mobile phones (android).

Alert is working fine.

I tried this:
I tried to render the modal popup using javascript/jquery -> not working,
I tried to render the modal popup by detecting browser if uc browser then render popup from js/jquery -> not working

Help me for this issue.
Also if you know best simulator for debugging js error through mobile then tell me

Answer (score 0):

It works when I called the modal popup onclick event instead of traditional way of calling the popup on id match.